# Не возвращает данные ajax formdata

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, formdata

Я должен вносить в бд записи через ajax, написал код, который с этим справляется, но ничего не выводит в success, а выводит в error. До меня никак не дойдет что не так. Уже и в массив все данные заношу, пытаясь через json_encode вывести но все никак. Подскажите, если можете, я в этом деле новичок, могу тупить жестко, надеюсь на понимание. 
Выводит в консоль: ["New group","Success!"]|
parsererror|
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#feedback").submit(function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('submit', 'send');
        fd.append('picture', $('#picture')[0].files[0]);
        fd.append('login', $('#login').val());
        fd.append('password', $('#password').val());
        fd.append('group', $('#group').val());
        fd.append('email', $('#email').val());

        $.ajax ({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: fd,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("SUCCESS" + data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText + '|\n' + status + '|\n' +error);
            }
        });
    });
});


<form id="feedback" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<label><p>Login</p><input type="text" id="login" name="login"></label>
<label><p>Password</p><input type="password" id="password" name="password"></label>
<label><p>Group</p><input type="text" id="group" name="group"></label>
<label><p>Email</p><input type="email" id="email" name="email"></label>
<label><p>Image</p><input type="file" id="picture" name="picture"></label>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Добавить">
```

и вот ajax.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array();
    $login = $db->escape($_POST['login']);
    $password = $db->escape($_POST['password']);
    $group = $db->escape($_POST['group']);
    $email = $db->escape($_POST['email']);
    $image = $_FILES['picture'];
    $reg = new Reg($login, $password, $group, $email, $image);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM `consumer` WHERE login = '{$reg->login}'");
    $row = $db->fetch_assoc($result);
    $reg->unique($row, 'Логин неуникален');
    $reg->regex(Reg::LOGIN_PATTERN, $reg->login, 'Некоректный login');
    $reg->regex(Reg::EMAIL_PATTERN, $reg->email, 'Некоректный email');
    $reg->groups($group);

    $path = 'images/';
    $explode = explode('.', $reg->image['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($explode);

    $reg->typeImg($ext, "Неподходящий тип картинки");
    $reg->sizeImage($reg->image, "Слишком большой размер картинки или её нет");
    $reg->userImage($reg->image, "Картинка не загрузилась!");

    if(empty($reg->getErrors())) {

        $uni = $db->query("SELECT groupId FROM `group` WHERE name = '$reg->group'");
        $gr = $db->fetch_assoc($uni);
        $groupid = $gr['groupId'];
        if($groupid) {
            $new = $db->query("INSERT INTO `consumer` (groupId, login, password, email, expirationDateAndTime, imageExtention) VALUES ('$groupid','$reg->login','".md5($reg->password)."','$reg->email','$reg->date','".$image['name']."')");
            $data[] = "УЖЕ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩАЯ ГРУППА";
        } else {
            $new1 = $db->query("INSERT INTO `group` (name) VALUES ('$reg->group')");
            $funcid = $db->getId();
            $new = $db->query("INSERT INTO `consumer` (groupId, login, password, email, expirationDateAndTime, imageExtention) VALUES ('$funcid','$reg->login','".md5($reg->password)."','$reg->email','$reg->date','".$image['name']."')");
            $data[] = "New group";
        }
        $funcid = $db->getId();

        if($new) {
            $namepic = $reg->nameImg($path, $funcid, $ext);

            $db->query("UPDATE consumer SET imageExtention = '$namepic' WHERE login = '$reg->login'");//переименовываем

            $data[] = "Success!";
        }else {
            $data[] = "Ошибка, не все поля заполнены";
        }
    } else {
        foreach($reg->getErrors() as $err) {
            $data[] = $err.'<br>';
        }
    }
    var_dump($data);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было всего лишь убрать var_dump($data), чтоб не путать данные отправлемые в json